# Content of cells reordered when accessoryType is changed to Checkmark

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I have an issue with TableViewCell height in iOS 7.1 when the checkmark is active in a row. When checkmark is on, the text of a cell is reordered and sometimes is put out of the bottom cell margin (see images), even if I resize the text label in Interface Builder.

Checkmark off:
[image]

Checkmark on:
[image]

This is my code for cells:

```
// MARK: Sections
    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return arrayDomande.count
    }

// MARK: Cells
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // 1 question & 5 answers
        return 1 + 5
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(QuestionCellIdentifier) as QuestionCellTableViewCell
            configureCell(cell, forTableView: tableView, atIndexPath: indexPath)
            cell.userInteractionEnabled = false

            return cell
        default:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(AnswerCellIdentifier) as AnswerCellTableViewCell
            configureCell(cell, forTableView: tableView, atIndexPath: indexPath)

            return cell
        }
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(QuestionCellIdentifier) as QuestionCellTableViewCell
            configureCell(cell, forTableView: tableView, atIndexPath: indexPath)
            cell.layoutSubviews()

            return (cell.contentView.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize).height + 10.0)
        default:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(AnswerCellIdentifier) as AnswerCellTableViewCell
            configureCell(cell, forTableView: tableView, atIndexPath: indexPath)
            cell.layoutSubviews()

            return (cell.contentView.systemLayoutSizeFittingSize(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize).height + 10.0)
        }
    }

    func configureCell(cell: UITableViewCell, forTableView: UITableView, atIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if (cell.isKindOfClass(QuestionCellTableViewCell)){
            let domanda = arrayDomande[atIndexPath.section]

            var attrs = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(19.0)]
            var qString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: domanda.numero.stringValue + ". ", attributes:attrs)
            var dString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: domanda.domanda)
            qString.appendAttributedString(dString)

            (cell as QuestionCellTableViewCell).testoLabel.attributedText = qString
        } else if (cell.isKindOfClass(AnswerCellTableViewCell)) {

            // Answers cache
            // Add answers to arrayRisposte only if aren't already present
            let domanda = arrayDomande[atIndexPath.section]
            if arrayRisposte.indexForKey(atIndexPath.section) == nil {
                let rispXDomanda: [Risposta] = domanda.risposte.allObjects as [Risposta]
                arrayRisposte[atIndexPath.section] = rispXDomanda.shuffled()
            }

            let answers: [Risposta] = arrayRisposte[atIndexPath.section]!
            (cell as AnswerCellTableViewCell).testoLabel.text = answers[atIndexPath.row - 1].risposta
            (cell as AnswerCellTableViewCell).selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
            if (forTableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows() != nil) && (contains(forTableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows() as [NSIndexPath], atIndexPath)) {
                (cell as AnswerCellTableViewCell).accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
            } else {
                (cell as AnswerCellTableViewCell).accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
            }
        }
    }

    // MARK: Select & Deselect
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSIndexPath? {
        var inpSelectedRow = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows()
        if inpSelectedRow != nil {
            for selectedIndexPath in inpSelectedRow! {
                if (selectedIndexPath.section == indexPath.section){
                    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(selectedIndexPath as NSIndexPath, animated: false)
                    tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(selectedIndexPath as NSIndexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
                }
            }
        }

        tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
        tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)?.layoutSubviews()
        return indexPath
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)?.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
    }
```

There is a way, when checkmark is added, to change height of cells based on new cell heights or a way to make text label fixed?
Thank you guys!

Andrea

Answer (score 0):

When checkmark is added. It will get added in accessory view. Accessory view takes some width which reduces the width of your label in the cell. So adjust your labels frame accordingly.

Comment: Thank you Dev. I modified label frame in Interface Building according to checkmark view but the text is always reordered when checkmark is added to cell. You can see examples of what I've done here: [images](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/3rnyas11tzp48wj/AABz2QvXNdt4V5WqkAxGcmQea)

Comment: the width reduces, it cannot accommodate the text. so it is wrapping the text to next line. Increase the height of the table you will be able to see the full text.